# How can I use a callback to pass an integer to a pointer in C?

Tags: c, pointers, callback

I have a function that prints 'Hello' and an integer.
I would like to use a callback function that passes the integer into the first function `A`.

```
//FUnction Pointers in C/C++
#include<stdio.h>
void A(int ree)
{
    printf("Hello %s", ree);
}
void B(void (*ptr)()) // function pointer as argument
{
    ptr();
}
int main()
{
    void (*p)(int) = A(int);
    B(p(3));
}
```

Desired result would be 'Hello 3'. This doesn't compile.

Comment: You have the correct signature for the function pointer. Define _that_ as the parameter to the `B` function: `void B(void(*p)(int))...`

Comment: First thing would be to get the code working *without* the callback. Reading the compiler error messages (like the mismatch between the %s conversion and the int parameter, that `A(int)` somehow does not seem to add up and that p(3) is a void expression where something non-void is expected) would help. Then try to reduce your post to *one*, *specific* question...

Comment: `p(3)` is a function *call*, evaluating to the result of that call.  To pass just a function pointer it would be simply `p`.  Or simply `A`.  And speaking of simply `A`, that is what you would initialize `p` with.  `A(int)` is not meaningful in that context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#include<stdio.h>
void A(int ree)
{
    printf("Hello %d", ree); // format specifier for int is %d
}
void B(void (*ptr)(int), int number) // function pointer and the number as argument
{
    ptr(number); //call function pointer with number
}
int main()
{
    void (*p)(int) = A; // A is the identifer for the function, not A(int)
    B(p, 3); // call B with the function pointer and the number
    // B(A, 3); directly would also be possible, no need for the variable p
}
```